# What does 'leering' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know what the verb [*leer*](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/leer) means:

> to look at someone in an unpleasant way that shows that you think they
>   are sexually attractive

[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English]

What does 'leering' mean in this context?

> The edifices were in a state of decay-shutters torn off, roofs
>   crumbled under the weight of heavy snows gone by, windows dusty and
>   *leering*.

from'Night shift' by Steven King

Comment: Look up the verb "to leer" in a dictionary, and tell me what you find.

Comment: I know 'leer'means.  'To look at someone in an unpleasant way that shows that you think they are sexually attractive.' in a longman dictionary.

Comment: Please see the edit and try to include your own research in your question.

Comment: OK, good.  So you know that to leer means to give a malicious look.  Does it make sense now that windows can seem to be the eyes of a building?  After all, light comes in through windows and people look out of them.

Comment: Next time, ask @deadrat what *patronising* means! If it is any consolation to you, I have been a native speaker for over 70 years, but would have had just as much trouble envisaging windows *leering* as you have had.

Comment: @WS2 You have much trouble envisaging the windows of a derelict house leering at you, yet you can read my mind to find my intentions?  Your comment is contemptible.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is a poetic way of saying that the subject feels that the buildings in question are looking at him or her in a disturbing way.

Taken literally, windows cannot leer: they cannot look, and leering is a kind of looking (specifically, a kind of looking which implies some sort of menace or bad intent, often sexual).  But, sometimes, perhaps when feeling scared, one may feel that a building has some sort of "spirit" or "personality" and is looking at us.

For a building to be leering at us would imply that it is looking at us in a way that makes us feel uncomfortable and possibly threatened, and I think that's what the author was trying to convey here.